# Why is my variable not defined when I step into another closure?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this function in a Laravel 4.2 app as part of a scheduled command. In PHPStorm, as soon as I enter the Mail::Send(){} closure, I can no longer refer to the current $request variable and therefore can't use it to find the attached user or the request data for sending the message. Why is this, and how can I make the variable defined and accessible?

```
public function fire()
{
    $requests = DataRequest::all();

    foreach($requests as $request)
    {
        if($request->status != "Completed")
        {
            Mail::send('emails.incompleteRequest', array('request' => $request), function($message)
            {
                //By this point, $request is not defined
                $requestid = $request->id;
                $user = RequestUser::where('userid', '=', $request->userid)->first();
                $message->to($user->email,$user->first_name . " " . $user->last_name)->subject('New Request Created');

            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's PHP. variables are scoped LOCALLY only, and are not inherited by "child" functions. Your closure is still a function, and normal PHP scoping rules apply. If you want the `$request` variable available, you have to make it available:

```
Mail::send([..snip..], function($message) use ($request) { ... }
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```